# Pandas: Calling value from another groupby table

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I would like to know more why .withcolumn cannot call data from another dataframe which has the same shape for the example below.

I want to get a ratio from the dataset which is `max()/min()`.

```
temp_table1 = df[df['column A'] == value1)].groupby('ID').max()
temp_table2 = df[df['column A'] == value1)].groupby('ID').min()
result_table = temp_table1.withColumn("Ratio", temp_table1['max(column B)']/
                                     temp_table2['min(column B)'])
```

I got this error,

> AnalysisException: Resolved attribute(s)

Comment: Please produce a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

Pyspark is not pandas. You can't use columns from different dataframes without a join. That said, you can combine the columns during the aggregation:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

result_table = df[df['column A'] == value1].groupby('ID').agg(
    (F.max('column B') / F.min('column B')).alias('Ratio')
)
```